# Как правильно создать массив php?

Tags: php

Я новичок и пытаюсь создать массив методами php. Нужно получить следующий массив:

```
Array ( [text] => dns, [select] => Me remember, [email] => justwalletpw@gmail.com,  )
```

Использую код:

```
foreach ($form_elements as $data) {

$validate_array[] = array($data->prefix => $json_array[$data->prefix],);

}
```

В итоге получаю массив:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [text] => dns ) [1] => Array ( [select] => Me remember ) [2] => Array ( [email] => justwalletpw@gmail.com ) )
```

Как мне получить массив как в первом примере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($form_elements as $data) {
    $validate_array[$data->prefix] = $json_array[$data->prefix];
}
```

исправлено после комментариев

Comment: Спасибо, но здесь неверный синтаксис и я получу ошибку. Вы не могли бы раскрыть свой пример более подробно?

Comment: сорян, неверно написал, конечно же:
    $validate_array[$data->prefix] = $json_array[$data->prefix];